# Add Join of data table to shapefile in ArcGIS Pro results in "<Null>" values for 90% of the records

Tags: arcgis-pro, attribute-joins, null

I'm new to ArcGIS and in over my head. I'm trying to join a shape file with a data table. The data table contains a calculated value I created in Excel. I thought this was going to be an easy, 5 minute task. I've been at this for days.

The files pertain to municipal housing issues. There are three particularly relevant fields:

- FullAddress: roughly 60k records. Letters and numbers.
- CommonField: roughly 30k records. The common field can have more than one Full Address. Made up of letters and numbers as text so the values containing something other than numbers are left-justified and the pure numbers are right-justified.
- BldAddress: a concatenation of House and Street (contains the same data as FullAddress but for the Unit field and created by concatenation rather than stripping out the Unit values from FullAddress).
- UnitsPerBuilding: roughly 17k records. The is the calculated field I’m trying to import and simply displays how many Full Addresses exist for each building. This field can have more than one CommonField and Full Address. Only numbers.

All I want to do is import one number field as a metric for housing density.

The problem is that the majority of the fields (roughly 90%) turn up as "". I have been unable to discern any pattern for this, other than the fact that about 90% of the non-Null values successfully imported are clustered conspicuously in one corner of the municipality.

Both the shapefile and the table originate from same municipality (the Shape file downloaded as a shapefile, and the data table downloaded as a CSV spreadsheet). It looks like the problem might be that the fields are not properly formatted. Unfortunately, I have been utterly unsuccessful despite days of trying to format the data table fields. I have tried importing the table as an XLS or a CSV file; importing into ArcGIS with and without the import tool (XLS to Table); "importing" a CSV or XLS* file into Excel rather than double click to open. The common field to join contains both letters and numbers and therefore it needs to be formatted as text. I have done that many times, and experimented with formatting the other fields as text, general, number.

I was advised the common field is 11 characters but the values range in number of characters. So I have tried padding the values with zeroes up to 11 characters but that also failed. Despite all these attempts at formatting, they make little difference: I recently compared the two attribute tables of the two files and have discovered:

1. The shapefile is mostly text fields, all text fields are unchecked for “Allow Null” field and range in length from 4 to 90 characters. The Common Field is formatted as a text field of 11 characters.
2. For the data table, I’ve imported as few as two fields and had the same result. CommonField was a text field up to 8000 (eight thousand) characters and UnitsPerBuilding is a long numeric of unspecified length, despite being formatted the same in the table prior to importing.

I have made sure that all field names are upper case and only contain letters and numbers (no spaces or other characters).

Comment: It can be very difficult to force a CSV to map column datatypes correctly, but if columns don't share a type, they can't be matched.

Comment: Thanks Vince. When you say "share a type" how specific must the match be? Is it enough that they are both "text" fields? It appears they don't need to match by length, but I'm wondering about the other elements including the Null False/True distinction.

Comment: What "Null False/True distinction"? Types must be comparable (`'1.000' <> 1`)

Comment: This is what I'm referring to. https://imgur.com/a/1ag6YSs